# How to show "Out of Stock" text in dropdown option?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, ce-1.7.0.2, dropdown-attribute, out-of-stock

How can I show "Out of Stock" text in dropdown option? See Chocolate Brownie Option in current and expected

[image: Current Showing]

[image: Expected Style]

Comment: I am not sure which file should I modify. Could you please suggest which file the code resides for attribute of complex product?

Comment: Has anyone done this for Magento 2?

Answer (score 7):

To show out of stock products go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory` and set `Display Out of Stock Products` to **yes**.

Now we'll need to rewrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` which you can do in your own module. Specifically the method `getJsonConfig`.

This method actually outputs a javascript string that is used to build the configurable product dropdowns.

Around line `197` you'll see

```
$info['options'][] = array(
   'id'        => $value['value_index'],
   'label'     => $value['label'],
   'price'     => $configurablePrice,
   'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
   'products'  => $productsIndex,
);
```

the `label` key is what you need to change. Checking for the stock of the products would look something like this

```
if (count($productsIndex) == 1) {
   $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
       ->loadByProduct($productsIndex[0]);
   if ($stockItem->getQty() == 0) {
      $value['label'] .= ' (out of stock)';
   }
}

$info['options'][] = array(
   'id'        => $value['value_index'],
   'label'     => $value['label'],
   'price'     => $configurablePrice,
   'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
   'products'  => $productsIndex,
);
```

Comment: Hi @sander-mangel, i have try your code, but not working. Out of Stock text still does not appear.

Comment: @AndhiIrawan I'm gonna need a whole lot more info than that to help you

Comment: It works partially. Now I can see the out of stock items in the drop down. but it doesn't mentioned (Out of Stock) in the drop down.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I've made an edit to the original answer to add a bit more clarity.

Comment: @ThomasHarding, Where is working answer !!?

Answer (score 1):

*app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php*

Make a custom module or put that file in local directory

1) line # 94 change

```
            if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                $products[] = $product;
            }
```

To

```
            //if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                $products[] = $product;
            //}
        }
```

2) Line # 197 change

```
                $info['options'][] = array(
                    'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                    'label'     => $value['label'],
                    'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                    'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                    'products'  => $productsIndex,
                );
```

To

```
                if (count($productsIndex) == 1) {
                   $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                       ->loadByProduct($productsIndex[0]);
                   if ($stockItem->getQty() == 0) {
                      $value['label'] .= ' (out of stock)';
                   }
                }
                $info['options'][] = array(
                    'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                    'label'     => $value['label'],
                    'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                    'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                    'products'  => $productsIndex,
                );
```

Comment: It works partially. Now I can see the out of stock items in the drop down. but it doesn't mentioned (Out of Stock) in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I think any of the solution given above so far would not work for configurable with more than 1 option set (more than 1 dropdown).

```
if (count($productsIndex)) {
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                   ->loadByProduct(end($productsIndex));
    if ($stockItem->getQty() == 0) {
        $value['label'] .= Mage::helper('catalog')->__(' (out of stock)');
    }
}
```

could be better in such cases.